# Debug current page in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, debugging

I have a MVC4 project in VS2012.

How can i debug the current open page in VS in the browser? When i select "current page" in project properties always the path with the Views folder is opened. The path should be without the Views folder.

When i select "specific page" and leave the textbox blank always the root directory is opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the MVC framework you are most likely using the routing system.
To specify your starting page you need to give your project the path you want to open and not the view name (and selecting "current page" doesn't work because Visual Studio has no idea what route can be used to display the view your are on).

You need to manually set the `Specific Page` in your project option (under the Web tab) to the path you want to use (let's say you want to call your `home` path, then just fill up the field with `home`).